# ASPNET Zero: Service Class isn't created in client side (Angular)

Tags: angular, aspnetboilerplate

In [ASP.NET ZERO Documentation](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/documents/zero/v6.6.0/Developing-Step-By-Step-Angular#edit-mode-for-phone-numbers) after running **nswag/refresh.bat** to regenerate *service-proxies* file in angular,
we add some changes to the phonecomponent :
in the phone.component.ts file we add these import :

```
import { PersonServiceProxy, PersonListDto, ListResultDtoOfPersonListDto, PhoneInPersonListDto, AddPhoneInput, AddPhoneInputType, PhoneInPersonListDtoType } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';
```

however doing that , i get an error telling the absence of members **AddPhoneInputType** and **PhoneInPersonListDtoType** in *service-proxies* file.

I get ***PhoneType*** Dto created instead  !!

I just followed the steps, i didn't figured out from where the problem comes?
any help ?
do i need to read another documentation before reading this ? if yes what are the pre-required documentations ?

## Update:

In my **service_proxies** file i have this enum:

```
export enum PhoneType {
    Mobile = 0, 
    Home = 1, 
    Business = 2, 
 }
```

In Github project instead of PhoneType enum there are these enums:

```
export enum PhoneInPersonListDtoType {
   _0 = 0, 
   _1 = 1, 
   _2 = 2, 
}

export enum AddPhoneInputType {
   _0 = 0, 
   _1 = 1, 
   _2 = 2, 
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code to show what you've done and the service-proxies file.

Comment: I am in ***Edit Mode For Phone  Numbers*** step,  i just copied/past  the code.
**service_proxies** file is a huge file i can't share it here , but i can tell that an enum PhoneType exist instead of enums AddPhoneInputType & PhoneInPersonListDtoType found in Github project !

Comment: Typescript Enum generation on AspNet Zero for Angular template has been changed. So now you don't have to use a dirty enum definition like PhoneInPersonListDtoType. use PhoneType enum.

Comment: @ismcagdas actually this is what i have done ; i used PhoneType enum by changing the code, but could you explain it more ? why the Typescript Enum generation on AspNet Zero have changed  ? How you knew that ? and why this is not mentioned in docs ?

Comment: @A.HADDAD For more explanation on why it changed, see [aspnetzero/aspnet-zero-core#1933 (comment)](https://github.com/aspnetzero/aspnet-zero-core/issues/1933#issuecomment-445787403). ismcagdas knew that because he is a maintainer (and he merged this particular change).

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is incorrect at there..
You should write :

```
import { PersonServiceProxy, PersonListDto, ListResultDtoOfPersonListDto, PhoneInPersonListDto, AddPhoneInput, PhoneType } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';
```

and change the other methods like this:

```
editPerson(person: PersonListDto): void {
    if (person === this.editingPerson) {
        this.editingPerson = null;
    } else {
        this.editingPerson = person;

        this.newPhone = new AddPhoneInput();
        this.newPhone.type = PhoneType.Mobile ;
        this.newPhone.personId = person.id;
    }
};

 getPhoneTypeAsString(phoneType: PhoneType): string {
    switch (phoneType) {
        case PhoneType.Mobile:
            return this.l('PhoneType_Mobile');
        case PhoneType.Home:
            return this.l('PhoneType_Home');
        case PhoneType.Business:
            return this.l('PhoneType_Business');
        default:
            return '?';
    }
};
```